# Set up Flask Application with test_client

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

I am trying to dockerize a Flask application I have with docker-compose. When I am trying to build the docker container, I am getting an error with the Flask application:

```
RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.
This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
an active HTTP request.  Consult the documentation on testing for
information about how to avoid this problem.
```

This [documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/reqcontext/) mentions to either use *test_client* or *test_request_context* to simulate a full request. Below is the code for the Flask application. I'm not sure how to integrate, any advice would be helpful.

**Code**

```
from flask import Flask, request, make_response
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    content = "Flask Server"
    fwd_for = "X-Forwarded-For: {}".format(
        request.headers.get('x-forwarded-for', None)
    )
    real_ip = "X-Real-IP: {}".format(
        request.headers.get('x-real-ip', None)
    )
    fwd_proto = "X-Forwarded-Proto: {}".format(
        request.headers.get('x-forwarded-proto', None)
    )

    output = "\n".join([content, fwd_for, real_ip, fwd_proto])
    response = make_response(output, 200)
    response.headers["Content-Type"] = "text/plain"

    return response
```

**Docker Compose**

```
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    build: ./app
    container_name: containerize_app_1
    command: gunicorn --chdir app/src --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --workers 2 "server:index()"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    expose:
      - 8000
    networks:
      - MyNetwork
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    container_name: containerize_nginx_1
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    ports:
      - 80:80
    depends_on:
      - app
    networks:
      MyNetwork:
        aliases:
          - flask-app

networks:
  MyNetwork:
```

**Docker Compose output with error**

```
docker-compose up
Starting containerize_app_1 ... done
Starting containerize_nginx_1 ... done
Attaching to containerize_app_1, containerize_nginx_1
nginx_1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
nginx_1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
nginx_1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
app_1    | [2021-12-14 20:39:51 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
app_1    | [2021-12-14 20:39:51 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (1)
app_1    | [2021-12-14 20:39:51 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
app_1    | [2021-12-14 20:39:51 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
app_1    | [2021-12-14 20:39:51 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
app_1    | [2021-12-14 20:39:51 +0000] [10] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
app_1    | Traceback (most recent call last):
app_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
app_1    |     worker.init_process()
app_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
app_1    |     self.load_wsgi()
app_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
app_1    |     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
app_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
app_1    |     self.callable = self.load()
app_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
app_1    |     return self.load_wsgiapp()
app_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
app_1    |     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
app_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 362, in import_app
app_1    |     app = eval(obj, vars(mod))
app_1    |   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
app_1    |   File "/var/www/app/src/server.py", line 8, in index
app_1    |     request.headers.get('x-forwarded-for', None)
app_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 432, in __get__
app_1    |     obj = instance._get_current_object()
app_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 554, in _get_current_object
app_1    |     return self.__local()  # type: ignore
app_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/globals.py", line 38, in _lookup_req_object
app_1    |     raise RuntimeError(_request_ctx_err_msg)
app_1    | RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.
app_1    | 
app_1    | This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
app_1    | an active HTTP request.  Consult the documentation on testing for
app_1    | information about how to avoid this problem.
app_1    | [2021-12-14 20:39:51 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
app_1    | [2021-12-14 20:39:51 +0000] [11] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
app_1    | Traceback (most recent call last):
app_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
app_1    |     worker.init_process()
app_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
app_1    |     self.load_wsgi()
app_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
app_1    |     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
app_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
app_1    |     self.callable = self.load()
app_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
app_1    |     return self.load_wsgiapp()
app_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
app_1    |     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
app_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 362, in import_app
app_1    |     app = eval(obj, vars(mod))
app_1    |   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
app_1    |   File "/var/www/app/src/server.py", line 8, in index
app_1    |     request.headers.get('x-forwarded-for', None)
app_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 432, in __get__
app_1    |     obj = instance._get_current_object()
app_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 554, in _get_current_object
app_1    |     return self.__local()  # type: ignore
app_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/globals.py", line 38, in _lookup_req_object
app_1    |     raise RuntimeError(_request_ctx_err_msg)
app_1    | RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.
app_1    | 
app_1    | This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
app_1    | an active HTTP request.  Consult the documentation on testing for
app_1    | information about how to avoid this problem.
app_1    | [2021-12-14 20:39:51 +0000] [11] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11)
app_1    | Traceback (most recent call last):
app_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 203, in run
app_1    |     self.manage_workers()
app_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 545, in manage_workers
app_1    |     self.spawn_workers()
app_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 617, in spawn_workers
app_1    |     time.sleep(0.1 * random.random())
app_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 245, in handle_chld
app_1    |     self.reap_workers()
app_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 525, in reap_workers
app_1    |     raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
app_1    | gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
app_1    | 
app_1    | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
app_1    | 
app_1    | Traceback (most recent call last):
app_1    |   File "/usr/local/bin/gunicorn", line 8, in <module>
app_1    |     sys.exit(run())
app_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 61, in run
app_1    |     WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
app_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 223, in run
app_1    |     super(Application, self).run()
app_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 72, in run
app_1    |     Arbiter(self).run()
app_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 232, in run
app_1    |     self.halt(reason=inst.reason, exit_status=inst.exit_status)
app_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 345, in halt
app_1    |     self.stop()
app_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 393, in stop
app_1    |     time.sleep(0.1)
app_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 245, in handle_chld
app_1    |     self.reap_workers()
app_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 525, in reap_workers
app_1    |     raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
app_1    | gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
nginx_1  | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
nginx_1  | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf differs from the packaged version
nginx_1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
nginx_1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
nginx_1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
nginx_1  | 2021/12/14 20:39:51 [emerg] 1#1: "user" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:1
nginx_1  | nginx: [emerg] "user" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:1
containerize_app_1 exited with code 1
containerize_nginx_1 exited with code 1
```

Comment: What is the full error message? Which line throws the error? `test_client` and `test_context` are for automated tests with `unittest` or `pytest` and probably have nothing to do with what you are seeing here.

Comment: The error comes up after I build the container with docker-compose. I'll update with the docker-compose file and the full error

Comment: maybe in command of web service, provide full gunicorn path

Answer (score 1):

Your error is with gunicorn, not flask, you are trying to run a function as an application. The correct way to do it would be:

```
gunicorn --chdir app/src --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --workers 2 "server:app"
```

Notice how instead of index() we are using app, because gunicorn expects a flask application object, otherwise you just give a function outside of the application context (thus the error). Change this in the docker-compose and it should work fine.